# Split a file based on number of groups in first column in bash and maximum line number

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Consider the following (sorted) file `test.txt` where in the first column `a` occurs 3 times, `b` occurs once, `c` occurs 2 times and `d` occurs 4 times.

```
a 1
a 2
a 1
b 1
c 1
c 1
d 2
d 1
d 2
d 1
```

I would like to split this file to smaller files with maximum 4 lines. However, I need to retain the the groups in the smaller files, meaning that all lines that start with the same value in column $1 need to be in the same file. The size of the group is in this example never larger than the desired output length.

The expected output would be:

file1:

```
a 1
a 2
a 1
b 1
```

file2:

```
c 1
c 1
```

file3:

```
d 2
d 1
d 2
d 1
```

From the expected output, you can see that it if two or more groups together have less than the maximum line number (here 4), they should go into the same file.

Therefore: `a` + `b` have together 4 entries and they can go into the same file. However, c + d have together 6 entris. Therefore c has to go in its own file.

I am aware of this Awk oneliner:

```
awk '{print>$1".test"}' test.txt
```

But this results in a separate file for each group. This would not make much sense in the real-world problem that I am facing since it would lead to a lot of files being transferred to the HPC and back and making the overhead too intense.

A bash solution would be preferred. But it could also be Python.

Comment: Your retaining lines in files logic is not clear much, kindly do add more details into your question for better understanding of this question.

Comment: I have updated the question. Is it clearly understandable now?

Comment: Sorry not clear, you said `meaning that all lines that start with the same value in column $1 need to be in the same file` but `b` is coming in first file? And on what basis file2 has only `c` values? Kindly make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Not clear what woudl happen if the sequence would have been `aaabbccdddee` for example.... there is some non-clear rule in your way of splitting the file

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia: your sequence would end in: `aaa` `bbcc` `ddd` `ee`

Comment: @JamesBrown: If more than one group have space in one file, then they should be in one file. sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Nvm I got it. Is the data always sorted? And if max 4 lines go to a file, what if there are 5 a:s?

Comment: @JamesBrown: Rule1: The file can never be larger than 4 lines. Rule2: All entries with the same value of $1 need to be in one file. Rule3: If there is enough space for more than one group, add the group to that file. From your comment: The d's are not added because 2*b+4*c > 4

Comment: @JamesBrown. I have updated that part in the question. Yes, always sorted. The groups are never larger than the maximum number of lines in the smaller files. Also, sorry if the question wasn't clear.

Comment: Is this also an optimization problem? If the data is: `aaa bb c dd` are a:s and the c in one file and b:s and d:s in another?

Comment: No. That wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I did a prototype in Awk but it doesn't work exactly right. I would perhaps do it in Python instead now that I see what I came up with. https://ideone.com/VudoYE

Comment: Thanks for your input @tripleee. The problem that I see is that the file has some 20 miillion lines. I will try though.

Comment: I am not an expert in awk, but could you use `>>` instead of `>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another awk. Had a busy day and this is only tested with your sample data so anything could happen. It creates files named `filen.txt`, where `n`>0:

```
$ awk -v n=4 '
BEGIN {
    fc=1                                         # file numbering initialized
}
{
    if($1==p||FNR==1)                            # when $1 remains same
        b=b (++cc==1?"":ORS) $0                  # keep buffering
    else {
        if(n-(cc+cp)>=0) {                       # if room in previous file
            print b >> sprintf("file%d.txt",fc)  # append to it
            cp+=cc                               
        } else {                                 # if it just won t fit
            close(sprintf("file%d.txt",fc))
            print b > sprintf("file%d.txt",++fc) # creat new
            cp=cc
        }
        b=$0
        cc=1
    }
    p=$1
}
END {                                            # same as the else above
    if(n-(cc+cp)>=0)
        print b >> sprintf("file%d.txt",fc)
    else {
        close(sprintf("file%d.txt",fc))
        print b > sprintf("file%d.txt",++fc)
    }
}' file
```

Comment: I have tested this quickly on part of my real-world example and - as far as I can tell right now - it works perfectly. Thank you very much. This is also a good study peace for myself!

Comment: I'm waiting for someone to pull a mean one-liner to solve this.

Comment: :) Well, when I wrote the question, I was indeed expecting some one-liner magic. But I think this is actually not as trivial as it might seem

Answer (score 2):

I hope I have understood your requirement correctly, could you please try following once written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v count="1" '
FNR==NR{
  max[$1]++
  if(!a[$1]++){
    first[++count2]=$1
  }
  next
}
FNR==1{
  for(i in max){
    maxtill=(max[i]>maxtill?max[i]:maxtill)
  }
  prev=$1
}
{
  if(!b[$1]++){++count1};
  c[$1]++
  if(prev!=$1 && prev){
    if((maxtill-currentFill)<max[$1]){count++}
    else if(maxtill==max[$1])        {count++}
  }
  else if(prev==$1 && c[$1]==maxtill && count1<count2){
    count++
  }
  else if(c[$1]==maxtill && prev==$1){
    if(max[first[count1+1]]>(maxtill-c[$1])){ count++ }
  }
  prev=$1
  outputFile="outfile"count
  print > (outputFile)
  currentFill=currentFill==maxtill?1:++currentFill
}
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

---

---

***Testing of above solution with OP's sample Input_file:***

```
cat Input_file
a 1
a 2
a 1
b 1
c 1
c 1
d 2
d 1
d 2
d 1
```

It will create 3 output files named outputfile1, outputfile2 and outputfile3 as follows.

```
cat outfile1
a 1
a 2
a 1
b 1
cat outfile2
c 1
c 1
cat outfile3
d 2
d 1
d 2
d 1
```

---

---

***2nd time testing(with my custom samples):*** With my own sample Input_file, lets say following is Input_file.

```
cat Input_file
a 1
a 2
a 1
b 1
c 1
c 1
d 2
d 1
d 2
d 1
d 4
d 5
```

When I run above solution then 2 outputfiles will be created with name `outputfile1` and `outputfile2` as follows.

```
cat outputfile1
a 1
a 2
a 1
b 1
c 1
c 1
cat outfile2
d 2
d 1
d 2
d 1
d 4
d 5
```

Comment: I really appreciate your input. I have tried the script and it weirdly didn't produce any output (but also no error).

Comment: Dear Ravinder. My bad, sorry, I thought this is sort of a typo. I have now placed the infile twice and it worked. How can I change the maximum number of lines in your script. Say, I have a 1 million line long file that I want to split to files with each 100000 lines?

Comment: @MKR, its calculating maximum number of files automatically(in first read of Input_file its doing that) :) I thought you need in generic way :)

Comment: Ah, I get it. Well that's a nice piece of work. I unfortunately need control over the maximum line numbers. I therefore keep JamesBrown's answer as the correct one. But thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed, bash and csplit):

```
f(){ 
    local g=$1
    shift
    while (( $#>1))
    do
         (($#==2)) && echo $2 && break
         (($2-$1==$g)) && echo $2 && shift && continue
         (($3-$1==$g)) && echo $3 && shift 2 && continue
         (($2-$1<$g)) && (($3-$1>$g)) && echo $2 && shift && continue
         set -- $1 ${@:3}
    done
}

csplit file $(f 4 $(sed -nE '1=;N;/^(\S+\s).*\n\1/!=;D' file))
```

This will split `file` into separate files named `xxnn` where `nn` is 00,01,02,...

The sed command produces a list of line numbers that splits the file on change of key.

The function `f` then rewrites these numbers grouping them in to lengths of 4 or less.

~